# ReactiveBase headers

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm experimenting with [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html) and so far have tried the DataSearch and ResultList components. I'm looking over the required  component to look at all the props and I see this

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="appname"
  credentials="abcdef123:abcdef12-ab12-ab12-ab12-abcdef123456"
  headers={{
      secret: 'reactivesearch-is-awesome'
  }}

>
    <Component1 .. />
    <Component2 .. />
</ReactiveBase>
```

If the app is already secured using Appbaseio and the credentials gives my React app access to my ES cluster hosted there... what exactly could headers be used for? At first I thought username and password but you wouldn't do that.

What would be some of the scenarios where I SHOULD/COULD use the headers prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `headers` are added to each request sent to the `url`. Normally you wouldn't need these. But in production you might want to add a layer of proxy server between your elasticsearch cluster and the client side ReactiveSearch code, this is where `headers` can be helpful.

You could add authentication in the flow. For example, you could restrict the elasticsearch calls to authenticated users by sending an access token via the `headers` prop and then verifying it at the proxy server ([example of proxy server](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-server)).

You could also implement some custom logic by adding custom headers and a logic to handle them at the proxy server.